# Convert sql query to hibernate criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate

I want to convert my sql query to hibernate criteria. Please help me out.

Here is my sql query:

```
 select USER_ID, sum(TH_TOTAL_SCORE) as score from t_o2_user_gameplay
 group by user_id order by score desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted is a native SQL query. Before you can translate that to using Criteria API, we need to know first about your Entity classes and its properties.

Here's a sample:

```
@Entity
public class UserGamePlay {
    private Long userId;
    private Long totalScore;
    ...
}
```

**HQL:**

```
SELECT ugp.userId, SUM(ugp.totalScore)
FROM UserGamePlay ugp
GROUP BY ugp.userId
ORDER BY SUM(ugp.totalScore)
```

**Criteria:**

```
List results = session.createCriteria(UserGamePlay.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.property("userId"), "userId" )
        .add( Projections.sum("totalScore"), "score" )
        .add( Projections.groupProperty("userId"), "userId" )
    )
    .addOrder( Order.asc("score") )
    .list();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...it works  for me...